# TikZ — rounded rectangle with transparent holes and custom width of borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I'm trying to draw a rounded rectangle with round "holes" using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64721/how-to-make-inner-and-outer-regions-transparent) but I need the rectangle borders to be thick and "holes" borders to be thin. Is there a better way to do so than:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    % Background    
    \fill[fill=black!10] (1.5, 1.5) rectangle (15, -15); 
    % Fill
    \fill[fill=black!2, even odd rule, rounded corners=0.5mm] 
        (0, 0) rectangle (10, -10) 
        (2, -2) circle[radius=1.25mm]
        (2, -5) circle[radius=1.25mm];
    % Rectangle border
    \draw[thick, rounded corners=0.5mm] (0, 0) rectangle (10, -10);
    % Holes borders
    \draw[thin] (2, -2) circle (1.25mm);
    \draw[thin] (2, -5) circle (1.25mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result image should look like this:

[image: rounded rectangle with transparent holes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code already outputs the image you posted, however, if you want to increase the difference, you can specify `ultra thin` or `ultra thick` (for additional fun). I suggest you only specify `ultra thin` though, because the other one makes the picture look ugly:

[image]

Comment: I know, what the code does :) But it could be better if could write something like this instead of drawing the filling and the borders separately: \draw[fill=black!2, even odd rule, rounded corners=0.5mm, thick] (0, 0) rectangle (10, -10) (2, -2) circle[radius=1.25mm, thin] (2, -5) circle[radius=1.25mm, thin];

Comment: @GeMir Ah, you want to simplify the command?

Comment: @GeMir No, you would need to specify the shapes of course. It's impossible to make it in one command, unless you do a `\newcommand`, but even then, you'd need to specify the shapes in the original definition of the `\newcommand`.

Comment: @GeMir By the way, you can also specify the line width like `[line width=.1pt]` (1pt is thick already).

Comment: My question was not about thickness definition, it was about simplifying the code. It seems to be impossible. Thank you.