# how to fill the area between polygon 1 and polygon 2 with color using tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    
%polygon1
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){P1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[P1](4,0){P2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[P2](0,4){P3}
\tkzDefParallelogram(P1,P2,P3)
\tkzGetPoint{P4}
\tkzDrawPolygon(P1,P2,P3,P4)
    
%polygon2
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){Q1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q1](2,0){Q2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q2](0,2){Q3}
\tkzDefParallelogram(Q1,Q2,Q3)
\tkzGetPoint{Q4}
\tkzDrawPolygon(Q4,Q3,Q2,Q1)
    
%how to fill the area between polygon 1 
%and polygon 2 with color using tkz-euclide?
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fill the second one with your background color, eg `\tkzDrawPolygon[fill=white](Q4,Q3,Q2,Q1)`

Comment: Thanks, Thruston, but I want it transparent...

Comment: In plain TikZ you can do this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245944/15036

Comment: @Thruston: Thanks! I'll save the link and follow the tip if a technical solution doesn't come up in the context of the tkz-euclide package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the solution is to use `TikZ` but a solution will be possible with `tkz-euclide` version 4 in a few days.

version 2 with only `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  
  \tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={
  (current bounding box.south west) --(current bounding box.north west)
   --(current bounding box.north east) --  (current bounding box.south east)
   -- cycle} }}
\makeatletter
\newif\iftkzClipOutPoly% 
\pgfkeys{tkzclippolygon/.cd,
       out code/.is if         = tkzClipOutPoly,
       out/.code               = \tkzClipOutPolyfalse}   

\def\tkzClipPolygon{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@ClipPolygon}{\tkz@ClipPolygon[]}}  
\def\tkz@ClipPolygon[#1](#2,#3){%
\tkzClipOutPolytrue
\pgfqkeys{/tkzclippolygon}{#1}%   
\iftkzClipOutPoly
\clip (#2)
   \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle[reverseclip];
\else
   \clip(#2)
    \foreach \pt in {#2,#3}{--(\pt)}--cycle[reverseclip] ;
\fi 
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
%polygon1
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){P1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[P1](4,0){P2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[P2](0,4){P3}
\tkzDefParallelogram(P1,P2,P3)
\tkzGetPoint{P4}

%polygon2
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){Q1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q1](2,0){Q2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q2](0,2){Q3}
\tkzDefParallelogram(Q1,Q2,Q3)
\tkzGetPoint{Q4}
\tkzDrawPolygon(P1,P2,P3,P4)
\begin{scope}
   \tkzClipPolygon[out](Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
  \tkzFillPolygon[blue!10](P1,P2,P3,P4)
\end{scope}

\tkzDrawPolygon(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With circles

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,4)
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](O,2)
\begin{scope}
  \tkzClipCircle[out,R](O,2)
  \tkzFillCircle[R,teal](O,4)
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

version 1

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
  
  \tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={
  (current bounding box.south west) --(current bounding box.north west)
   --(current bounding box.north east) --  (current bounding box.south east)
   -- cycle} }}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
%polygon1
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){P1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[P1](4,0){P2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[P2](0,4){P3}
\tkzDefParallelogram(P1,P2,P3)
\tkzGetPoint{P4}

%polygon2
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){Q1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q1](2,0){Q2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[Q2](0,2){Q3}
\tkzDefParallelogram(Q1,Q2,Q3)
\tkzGetPoint{Q4}
\tkzDrawPolygon(P1,P2,P3,P4)
\begin{scope}
  \clip (Q1)-- (Q2) -- (Q3) -- (Q4) -- cycle [reverseclip]; 
  \tkzFillPolygon[blue!10](P1,P2,P3,P4)
\end{scope}

\tkzDrawPolygon(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Alain.
Great job!
I will wait for the next version.

Comment: Please, do it also to circles. :)

Comment: @LuisFerreira It's already done!

Comment: I have an error... :/




! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tkzclipc/out' and I am going t
o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10   \tkzClipCircle[out,R](O,2)

Comment: @LuisFerreira No you need to wait the next version 4.0 ... newt week !

Comment: OK! :) Thanks for your work

Comment: @AlainMattes I found a problem : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/629231/tkz-euclide-vs-xelatex-vs-pdflatex

Answer (score 0):

What about less code, without tkz-euclide, and more results?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %squares
    \filldraw[cyan!50] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \filldraw[white] (1,1) rectangle (4,4);
    
    \filldraw[cyan!50] (0,-6) rectangle (5,-1);
    \filldraw[white] (1,-4) rectangle (3,-2);
    %circles
    \filldraw[cyan!50] (8,2.5) circle (2.5);
    \filldraw[white] (8,2.5) circle (1.5);
    
    \filldraw[cyan!50] (8,-3.5) circle (2.5);
    \filldraw[white] (7,-3) circle (1);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want also borders:

[image]

you modify a little bit the code:

```
%squares
\filldraw[fill=cyan!50,line width=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\filldraw[fill=white,line width=1pt] (1,1) rectangle (4,4);
```

Comment: Less code ? Are you sure ? You have not defined any points. The goal is to do geometry, not decoration. If I have to do this kind of figure again I prefer not to use numerical values. The code to fill  est fait en deux lignes :` \clip (Q1)-- (Q2) -- (Q3) -- (Q4) -- cycle [reverseclip]; 
  \tkzFillPolygon[blue!10](P1,P2,P3,P4)` and Last remark, you put color twice on the inner part and you must adapt the last one with the color of the background

Comment: No point marked in your picture. So no need to use your excellent package.

Comment: The idea in general is to define the fixed points and then not to use coordinates. The points are indeed defined and not marked but one can imagine that the code is not limited to these figures. `TikZ` est un outil génial et `filldraw  ... rectangle` c'est pratiquement identique à `\tkzFillPolygon`

Comment: Ok, I say 'in your picture' no need to call the 'artiglierie lourde'. 'Par contre', if you add in your picture the points and other objects, tkz-euclide is very useful.