# tkz-euclide vs XeLaTeX vs pdfLaTeX

Tags: tkz-euclide

Good morning, Alain!

I tried the example on page 145 of the tkz-euclide manual
(January 4, 2022 Documentation V.4.00)
and found it works with pdflatex but it doesn't work with xelatex.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){P1}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){P2}
\tkzDefPoint(4,4){P3}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){P4}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){Q1}
\tkzDefPoint(3,1){Q2}
\tkzDefPoint(3,3){Q3}
\tkzDefPoint(1,3){Q4}
\tkzDrawPolygon(P1,P2,P3,P4)
\begin{scope}
\tkzClipPolygon[out](Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)
\tkzFillPolygon[teal!20](P1,P2,P3,P4)
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawPolygon(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex]

[image: xelatex]

> pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)

> XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021)

Comment: It works for me with Lualatex and Xelatex! This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.12.24)  6 JAN 2022 12:05

Comment: Do you have tkz-base 4 installed? In principle it is independent but there are shared files and I may have made a mistake.