tikz: arrows, even odd rule, and trapezium shape; how to draw an arrow through a hole
I would like to tikz something like this:

With:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245944
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (hole) at (1ex, 3ex);
    \node[trapezium, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60, minimum width=4ex, minimum height=4ex, rotate=30] (layer) {};
    \path[draw, even odd rule]
        {(layer.top left corner) -- (layer.bottom left corner) -- (layer.bottom right corner) -- (layer.top right corner) -- cycle}
        {($(layer.bottom left corner)+(hole)$) ellipse [draw, x radius=1.0ex,y radius=0.8ex, rotate=0]};
    \draw[-]  ($(layer.bottom left corner)+(hole)$)            -- +(0ex, 4ex);
    \draw[->] ($(layer.bottom left corner)+(hole)+(0ex,-3ex)$) -- +(0ex,-2ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I can produce:

However, this solution feels crude (redrawing the trapezoid, splitting the arrow in two, ...) and a bit lifeless.
How can I use even odd rule with trapezium without the extra \path and draw an arrow through the even odd rule hole without guessing the size of the inter-arrow gap?

This uses the even odd rule on a \clip.  Note that you still have to separate the foreground and background for 3d objects.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\standaloneenv{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (hole) at (1ex, 3ex);
    \node[trapezium, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60, minimum width=4ex, minimum height=4ex, rotate=30] (layer) {};
    \path[draw]
        (layer.top left corner) -- (layer.bottom left corner) -- (layer.bottom right corner) -- (layer.top right corner) -- cycle
        ($(layer.bottom left corner)+(hole)$) coordinate(C) ellipse [draw, x radius=1.0ex,y radius=0.8ex, rotate=0];
    \path[->] (C) ++(0ex, 4ex) -- ++(0ex,-8ex);% grow bounding box
    \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
    \clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle  (current bounding box.north east)
        (layer.top left corner) -- (layer.bottom left corner) -- (layer.bottom right corner) -- cycle;
    \draw[->] (C) ++(0ex, 4ex) -- ++(0ex,-8ex);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks for the response! For \clip[even odd rule], I'm getting Package tikz Error: Extra options not allowed for clipping path command... Does this approach require any specific package versions?

Oops.   You can use it with scope, but apparently you don't need it at all (default).

I appreciate this answer, but still hope to get rid of the extra \path.
